# Estou usando pdo prepare statement não aparece erro e nem introduz nada no banco de dados

Tags: php

index.php

```
<?php 
    require 'banco.php';
    $usuario = new usuario("localhost","blog","root","");
    $usuario -> inserir("dfd","dvd@gmail.com",123,"Ola mudfndo");
?>
```

banco.php

```
<?php 
    class usuario{
        private $pdo;
        public function __construct($host,$dbname,$dbusser,$dbpass){
            try {
                $this ->pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$dbname.";host=".$host,$dbusser,$dbpass);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "Falhou: ".$e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        public function inserir($nome,$email,$senha,$menssagem){
            $sql = $this ->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario SET nome =:nome,email =:email,senha =:senha,menssagem =:menssagem ");
            $sql ->bindParam(':nome',$nome);
            $sql ->bindParam(':email',$email);
            $sql ->bindParam(':senha',$senha);
            $sql ->bindParam(':menssagem',$menssagem);
            $sql ->execute();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Espera que já meto a pergunta de nosso, sou novo aqui .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sintaxe do insert está errada. 
Ela deveria ser algo por exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO NOME_DA_TABELA (CAMPOS_QUE_DESEJA_INSERIR_DADOS) VALUES (VALORES_DOS_CAMPOS).
```

O que foi digitado na pergunta foi uma parecida com a sintaxe do UPDATE:

```
$sql = $this ->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario SET nome =:nome,email =:email,senha =:senha,menssagem =:menssagem ");
```

Sendo assim, altere para:

```
$sql = $this ->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario (nome,email,senha,menssagem) values (:nome,:email,:senha,:menssagem)");
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta Israel Zebulon mas mesmo assim não funcionou

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda Israel Zebulon funcionou, tinha também um erro de escrita da tabela